# Combine two apis in laravel

Tags: php, algorithm, laravel

I want to combine APIs in laravel.

Get data from first api => update data in second api.

And vice versa

Get from second api => update in first api.

Problem: sometimes api calls may fail so I need to store somehow failed calls to execute them later.

Currently I have some tables to handle this.

1. Insert record into table indicating which call should be executed
2. ...
3. ...
4. Extract records with calls and try to execute every call.
5. If it is ok, remove record from table
6. Otherwise leave it untouched and process to next calls

May be there is a better approach?

Comment: There are endless ways to skin a cat. I  believe your solution is simple and if it meets your needs go for it.

Comment: @prime that metaphor sounds very disturbing.